# Azure Web App - Include An Editable Pre-Header File?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-webapps

Trying to figure out a good way to have an easily editable chunk of content that I can include in the header of my Azure Web App.

Think of a 'pre-header' notification message that sits above my header.  Maybe 99% of the time, its empty but occasionally I will put in a "Site Down for Maintenance in 1 Hour" warning message or some other notification.  I don't want to have to go through the entire Publish / Push via Devops Swap dance - I just want to go in somewhere (Azure Blob or File Storage) with an online editor, make some quick changes to the notice and **voila** it appears on the site.

I'm sure there are many ways to do this but is there an easy way to:

1. Have a file in Azure Storage that I can easily edit via browser?  I've done "Static Sites" in Azure Storage before but I'm not 100% sure thats the best route for me.
2. How best to include that file in my Azure Web App (ASP Core MVC)?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case somebody else has this need, I figured it out last night.  I just remembered - why not use the Azure Kudu Diagnostic Console editor to modify the files?

> Kudu is found in Azure Dashboard for your Web App in left menu under "Development Tools / Advanced Tool" option.  Then click on Debug Console/CMD in the Kudu menu for a little GUI which you can navigate the Azure WebApp site directories and edit any file.

The other trick is to include the file.  I put a file in my Visual Studio project called '/includes/preheader.htm'.  In my /Shared/_Layout.cshtml page, I have the following code:

```
//if you have a 'wwwroot' folder in your VS project, you will actually
//need to put wwwroot TWICE to get the relative path on Azure Web App.
//it will be different on your local machine for testing, 
//you will need somthing like @"..\[PROJECTNAME]\wwwroot\include\preheader.htm"

string azureincludepath = @"..\wwwroot\wwwroot\include\preheader.htm";
string preheader = String.Empty;

//ignore any exceptions we get trying to read the file.  
//you don't want your entire site down if you accidentally delete your include file

try
{
    preheader = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(azureincludepath);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //do nothing - just move on.  no preheader will show
}

...


//later in the html <body> where I want it
@Html.Raw(preheader)
```

Disclaimer:  I'm sure this breaks about a half-dozen security recommendations and my understanding is that you should really never use @Html.Raw for showing content on your site.  If you think this is a terrible solution from that perspective, feel free to comment.